# Gulp-cdnizer: replace local link with cdn only for specific files

Tags: deployment, gulp, bower, cdn

everyone!

Does anybody know how to replace local link to js files with cdn links only for specific files? 
I'm using gulp and bower for front-end deployment.

So, the task is following: bower_components folder contains angular, jquery, bootstrap and so on folders, links to .js files is set in index.html like

```
 <head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script></pre>
....

</head>
```

How to use gulp-cdnizer to get cdn link for angular only?

Expected (**desired**) result

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-route.min.js></script>
....

</head>
```

Could you give example for gulp task?

```
gulp.src("./src/index.html")
    .pipe(cdnizer([
        {
            file: 'vendor/angular/angular.js',
            package: 'angular',
            cdn: '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/${ major }.${ minor }.${ patch }/${ filenameMin }'
        // some actions to get purpose
        }
    ]))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("./dist"));
```